# unable to get array from ajax to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an array of objects that I'm passing from view to controller using ajax.
Array data is:
[image]

My ActionMethod is:

```
public JsonResult AddQuestionsToStep(long stepId, string questionText, string questionType, string correctAnswer = "", List<QuestionOption> choices = null)
```

I'm receiving other variables data and count for choices array but the data in choices array is not mapped.i.e, `OptionName` that has value on client side is null on server side. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the code how you are building the choices objects? From your screenshot it seems that OptionId contains function rather than string

Comment: I'm using knockoutJs. Even if `OptionId` is a function, shouldn't it map `OptionName` property?

Comment: Actualy, you are trying to send array of javascript objects, i don't think your backend will be able to process that anyway.  Try to send it as JSON.stringify(choices) and parse it on your backend side

Comment: when I send `JSON.stringify(choices)` , it doesn't even receive the count in `List<QuestionOption> choices` parameter. let me try dynamic `JObject.Parse(choice);`

Comment: Yes, because you are getting a string representation of your Object Array. In your original code, you are receiving count, because you are sending array of objects, but all of them are undefined, as you can't post an array of javascript objects.

Comment: i posted a suggested solution in an answer, please try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `choices` is a javascript array of Objects,  serialize it and parse it on your backend:

```
choices: JSON.stringify(choices)
```

On your backend just parse the json:

```
List<QuestionOption> choices = (List<QuestionOption>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(choicesJson, typeof(List<QuestionOption>));
```

Comment: Thanks mike, it worked! I should post the question earlier, I wasted my whole day.

Comment: Btw. if you don't mind, post the line you use to parse it on your backend, so i can update the asp.net code in the answer to a working solution, i was just blind guessing the asp code

Comment: sure, I parsed using `List<QuestionOption> choices =
                (List<QuestionOption>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(choicesJson, typeof(List<QuestionOption>));`